# Is it possible to overflow returned values of a method?

Tags: java, overflow

Does overflow occur only with variables and not with returned values of methods?

In java, when we type :

```
long number = Long.MAX_VALUE;
long newNumber = number +1;
```

we got an overflow, but when I have tried:

```
long number = Math.round(Long.MAX_VALUE + 0.6);
```

I don't get an overflow, but I do get always the max value of a long.

Is this always the case for all methods in java, where we return values greater than the maximal value of a data type?

Comment: seeing as your long newNumber = number+1; is also likely written in a method, what do you think?

Comment: You are operating on **doubles** in your second example, not longs.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question:

> Why does `long value = Math.round(a_double_bigger_than_long_MAX_VALUE);` not overflow?

You can see [@rzwitserloot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78060914/1509264) for why `Long.MAX_VALUE + 0.6` isn't actually greater than `Long.MAX_VALUE` but to answer the spirit of the question.

If you look at the documentation for [`java.lang.Math.round(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-):

> #### round
>
> ```
> public static long round(double a)
> ```
>
> Returns the closest `long` to the argument, with ties rounding to positive infinity.
>
> Special cases:
>
> - If the argument is `NaN`, the result is `0`.
> - If the argument is `negative infinity` or any value less than or equal to the value of `Long.MIN_VALUE`, the result is equal to the value of `Long.MIN_VALUE`.
> - If the argument is `positive infinity` or any value greater than or equal to the value of `Long.MAX_VALUE`, the result is equal to the value of `Long.MAX_VALUE`.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `a` - a floating-point value to be rounded to a `long`.
>
> Returns:
>
> - the value of the argument rounded to the nearest `long` value.

So `round(double)` is doing exactly what the documentation states it should - if you provide a value greater then `Long.MAX_VALUE` then it returns `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

```java
long value = Math.round(1e100);
System.out.println(value == Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Outputs `true`.

Answer (score 1):

NB: At time of writing, 2 answers already exist that are both incorrect.

> `long number = Math.round(Long.MAX_VALUE + 0.6);`

Careful. This does a lot of things silently. It's crucial to understand how javac compiles this to understand why overflow does not occur.

`Long.MAX_VALUE + 0.6` is, on its face, impossible. Java does not allow heterogenous mathematical operations, and `Long.MAX_VALUE` is of type `long`, whereas `0.6` is of type `double`.

However, java's rulebook (The Java Language Specification) instructs the compiler to **silently** cast one of the two sides to the other's type *if* that is 'not lossy', and then enumerates exactly what is considered 'not lossy':

- `byte` to `int`
- `short` to `int`
- `char` to `int`
- `int` to `long` (and therefore all the above to `long` as well)
- `float` to `double`
- `long` to `double` (and therefore all the above).

The only thing that doesn't silently upconvert to a `double` if needed, is `boolean`.

Hence, what javac actually ends up doing, is this:

```
long number = Math.round(((double) Long.MAX_VALUE) + 0.6);
```

And this is tricky. Because where the java rulebook says that it isn't lossy to convert a `long` to a `double`, **the rulebook is wrong**.

It **is** lossy. You can prove this mathematically: Both are specced to be 64-bit, and you can't magically store *more* things in one 64-bit thing than another 64-bit thing. And doubles can store, for example, 0.5 - which is a number that `long` cannot. That extra expressiveness cannot come for free. For every `double` value that is not representable as a `long`, there must be at least one `long` value that is not representable as a `double`. And there are **a lot** of double values that aren't representable as a long, thus, as a flipside of the coin, a **a lot** of `long` values that cannot be losslessly converted to a double.

**Almost all `long` values beyond `[-2^52, +2^52]` LOSE PRECISION when converted to a double, even though `javac` will silently inject a cast to do this!**

And, naturally, `Long.MAX_VALUE` is, in fact, not in that 'safe' range.

So, all bets are off now. Your question boils down to: "Why is math just wrong when I write code such that the compiler will silently inject casts to `double`, and the numbers are really large `long` values?" - and the answer is: Because.. that's just how it is.

Forget about `Math.round`. Run this code:

```
long a = Long.MAX_VALUE;
double b = a;
double c = b + 0.6;
System.out.println(b == c);
```

This prints `true` which seems nuts. How in the blazes can it be that `a` is equal to `a + 0.6`?

doubles aren't magic. They are limited in what they can represent - at most `2^64` different numbers are "blessed" - a number that `double` can represent. All other numbers (and there are an infinite amount of them!) are **silently** rounded to the nearest blessed number. The nearest blessed number to `roundToNearestBlessed(MAX_VALUE) + roundToNearestBlessed(0.6)` is.. `roundToNearestBlessed(MAX_VALUE)` itself. Adding 0.6 does nothing.

This is logical: The distance between blessed numbers increases as you get away from 0, and around `2^52`, the distance is **more than 1.0**. `Long.MAX_VALUE` is `2^63-1`, _well beyond that point where doubles are less expressive than longs`.

Thus, no wonder then that adding `0.6` does absolutely nothing whatsoever.

So, why does no overflow occur here? Because adding `0.6` to a huge double value like that does nothing whatsoever.

Had it, somehow - then overflow still does not occur because doubles do not overflow (they turn themselves into the special number `Double.Infinity` instead), and the `round()` method doesn't either - it just rounds anything larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE` to `Long.MAX_VALUE`. **Which does not occur here** - the input you have provided isn't, in fact, larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

When you compute `Long.MAX_VALUE + 0.6` the value is a *double* type since one of the operands is decimal, then Math.round behaves like it is supposed to: (from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html))

*If the argument is positive infinity or any value greater than or equal to the value of Long.MAX_VALUE, the result is equal to the value of Long.MAX_VALUE.*

---

As @rzwitserloot pointed out below, not only adding 0.6 returns a *double* value, but it is also basically guaranteed to return a value equal to `Double.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE)` due to the loss of precision that comes with the conversion.

Comment: This answer is essentially incorrect; it does not actually explain what's happening. Java inserts a cast to `(double)` for you silently because it erroneously thinks casting longs to doubles is always safe (it's not, for longs beyond `2^52`), and from there the game is pretty much lost entirely. The docs you talk about refer to e.g. `Math.round(1e100)` or something similarly enormous. I do not think the answer can be salvaged.

Comment: To show how completely wrong this answer is: `long a = Long.MAX_VALUE; double b = a; double c = b + 0.6; System.out.println(b == c);` -- prints `true`. So, when you say: It's because the spec says numbers above Long.MAX_VALUE are rounded to MAX_VALUE - no, that number isn't beyond MAX_VALUE at all.

Comment: You are right, I didn't consider the loss of precision in the conversion to double